# Calling function from an object instance not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, instance

I have this code here:

```
var myRequest = new httpReq.myRequest(buffer,socket);
if(!myRequest.hasSucceded()){ //return error
    return;
}
arr=myRequest.getCookies();
....
```

and i definitely have this function on my myRequest object:

```
function myRequest(buffer, socket) {
    ...
    this.cookies = new Array();
    ...
    //returns the cookie array
    function getCookies() {
        return this.cookies;
    }
    ...
}
exports.myRequest = myRequest;
```

and i get an error saying:

```
TypeError: Object #<myRequest> has no method 'getCookies'
```

Y U  NO GIVE COOKIES???

help please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring getCookies as a local function.

To call it externally, you need to create a property getCookies on your object so you can call it.

Try this:

```
function myRequest(buffer, socket) {
...
this.cookies = new Array();
...

//returns the cookie array
this.getCookies = function() {
    return this.cookies;
}

...

}
```

You also could just do `myRequest.cookies` instead of `myRequest.getCookies()`

Comment: i knew i forgot something... thanks alan it worked will accept ans in couple mins

Answer (score 2):

```
function myRequest(buffer, socket) {
    this.cookies = [];
}

myRequest.prototype.getCookies = function () {
    return this.cookies;
};
```

First, declaring getCookies inside constructor directly causes this method to be a private method, which only lives within the constructor.

Second, usually it is considered a good practice to define the prototype getCookies outside the constructor. If it is defined in the constructor (like, this.getCookies = function () {...}), this method would need to be initialized every time when this prototype is instantiated.